# How to use use-package with built-in packages?

Tags: use-package

For the sake of tidiness, I'd like to group setq(s) under single, related banner.
Let's say I want to set the value of compilation-scroll-output in "compilation" unit like this:

```
(use-package compilation
  :init
  (progn
    (setq compilation-scroll-output t)))
```

All I get is:

```
Could not load compilation
```

How is it?

Comment: FWIW, use `describe-variable` or `describe-function` to find out which package a var or func is in, then look down at the `provide` call to find out the package name.

Comment: Your code to set `compilation-scroll-output` is a noop, it should be `(progn (setq compilation-scroll-output t))`

Comment: Thank you npostavs. For some unknown reason I was trying to use ' as an alias of setq.

Comment: @npostavs I didn't even notice that.. fixed that in my answer too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The package's name is `compile`.

Below should work.

```el
(use-package compile
  :init
  (progn
    (setq compilation-scroll-output t)))
```

---

It would be worthwhile to note **@JordonBiondo**'s comment on how to figure out a package's name.

If you want to know which package a variable belongs to, do `C-h v` or `M-x describe-variable` followed by the var name (for a function name, `C-h f` or `M-x describe-function`). From the *Help* window that pops up, navigate to the package's `.el` file and see the `(provide ..)` call to find out the package name.

Comment: Use-package's syntax around the keywords is slightly unusual.  The forms following most of the keywords are bundled up for that keyword for you.  So the progn is rarely needed. ```(use-package compile :init (message "init for compile") (setq compilation-scroll-output t))```

Comment: @BenHyde That's correct; `progn` is not required but I use it for convenience. If I have bunch of forms under `:init` and a bunch of forms under `:config`, having wrapped them in `(progn ..)` makes it very convenient to eval the whole of `:init` or `:config` using `C-x C-e`.